# shell, job control for receiving end of the pipe

Tags: bash, shell, unix, job-control

I don't understood, why I can't run some process ("cat" in this example) in background and later make it foreground:

```
$ dash
$ f() { cat </dev/stdin > /dev/stdout &  sleep 1; fg ; }
$ sleep 2 | f
dash: 1: fg: job (null) not created under job control
$ set -m 
$ sleep 2 | f
dash: 1: fg: job (null) not created under job control
$ f() { set -m; cat </dev/stdin > /dev/stdout &  sleep 1; fg ; }
$ sleep 2 | f
dash: 5: fg: job (null) not created under job control
```

Why every time I'm getting error message?

At some time I have no such messages when running function "f" without pipe:

```
$ set +m
$ f
cat 0</dev/stdin 1>/dev/stdout
^C
$ set -m
$ f
cat 0</dev/stdin 1>/dev/stdout
^C
```

Comment: Looks like job control is enabled in shell only if this shell process is the process group leader.  Another example, which gives strange result:
    $ sleep 2 | sh -c "set -m; cat </dev/stdin > /dev/stdout &  sleep 1; fg"
    cat 0</dev/stdin 1>/dev/stdout
    sh: 1: Cannot set tty process group (No such process)

Comment: When you run the function in a pipeline, it's run in a subshell, but job control is only available in the main shell.

Comment: Is this `dash` or `bash`?